# SpeechKit/SpeechKit In Extension App like Custom Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, swift, xcode6-beta5

I have tried any posible way of importing this framework in my custom extension keyboard, but I have failed all the trials that I think is possible.

1st.
I have tried it in full swift code, importing that framwork using bridging header. But, Most of its command isn't compatible with swift, got an error in enumeration -> NSUInteger in ObjC -> swift always complains, can't even use convert type.

2nd
I have also tried full Objective-C coding. Implementing its function was easy task. But Fails to use this framework. Can't import it in extension App. I have also use bridging header but got an error. "File not found" even though if you do command click, you'll be jumped to its framework. (means indexing is success. and xcode find it clear.). In the end, I think this framework doesn't work with extension, so far.

so, Any idea of how to implement this correctly? advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You may want to check out [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25538579) (that I ended up answering after I figured it out).  I think these are the same issue, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll tackle this later. :D