# Cannot load images from Twitter app within share extension

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, share-extension

I'm implementing a share extension that sends images to a server for computation.
In addition to my [progress bar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758062/use-of-svprogresshud-in-share-extension), I'm not able to use the images from Twitter app. Here is the code I'm using which is working in many other third party apps.

```
if let inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
            if let itemProvider = inputItem.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
                if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String) { [unowned self] (imageData, error) in
                        let url = imageData as! URL
                        self.sendToServer(localUrl: url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The error I have is the following: `Could not cast value of type 'NSConcreteData' (0x1a8d45700) to 'NSURL' (0x1a8d36a10)` and occurs for this part of the code `let url = imageData as! URL`.

It seems that the item is of type `image`. Any idea why that is happening while it works for the other apps?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix that by using the following code, which takes into account different ways the photo is passed by the `itemProvider`.

```
itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String){ [unowned self] (data, error) in
                            let myImage: UIImage?
                            switch data {
                            case let image as UIImage:
                                myImage = image
                            case let data as Data:
                                myImage = UIImage(data: data)
                            case let url as URL:
                                let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url.absoluteURL)
                                myImage = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
                            default:
                                //There may be other cases...
                                print("Unexpected data:", type(of: data))
                                myImage = nil
                            }
                            self.sendToServer(imageData: myImage!, imageName: myImageName)
                        }
```